# Why are some badges not shown on the list of badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-badges

I just noticed in the "recent badges" section on SO that a few users earned a "C++" and "Java" badge but those badges are not listed on the "Badges" page (which is supposed to show all badges possible. I'm sure that other languages have badges as well, but it leads to the question of what other badges are available that aren't actually listed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are "general" and "tags" tabs in the upper-right of the badges page.  "C++" and "Java" badges will be listed with the tags.

Comment: dang...didn't even see those tabs!

Comment: Aww, beat me by a couple of seconds ( *possibly less* ). **`+1`** for you.

Comment: It took me at least a month to figure out why all the tag badges had disappeared from the badges page. It's not the most visible place to put tabs, I guess.

Comment: It took me a while to find it too.  I think your eye gets drawn to the left on that page, making the tabs hard to see.

Answer (score 4):

You need to click "Tags" On [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags), [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags), [SU](https://superuser.com/badges?tab=tags), or [SF](https://serverfault.com/badges?tab=tags)

[image]

Comment: I realized I answered a duplicate question, so I moved my answer here

Comment: No new upvote from me, forget it!

Comment: I would only want it if you upvoted both questions

Comment: +1 for freehand circles

Answer (score 3):

Those particular badges are created **on Demand**, they don't exist until someone earns the badge.

Since they aren't like the other badges, they get their own [tab](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags).