# Badges missing from Badges List

Tags: support, badges

It seems that you can get badges from getting a certain number of upvotes in a given tag.
Jon Skeet has several of those, but those badges are not shown on the Badges page.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14680/why-are-some-badges-not-shown-on-the-list-of-badges

Comment: My Search-Fu is weak

Comment: Use Google :) http://www.google.com/search?q=missing+badges+list+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 8):

You need to click "Tags" On [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags), [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags), [SU](https://superuser.com/badges?tab=tags), or [SF](https://serverfault.com/badges?tab=tags)

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so2.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so2.png)

Comment: Provided with, of course, free-hand circle

Comment: Added my answer to the duplicate question